# Move subview in front of other subview without preventing interaction

Tags: ios, swift

I have a view controller and its subview `CardViewController`. This card view contains a table which is supposed to display suggestions to the cities the user input into the search bar. 
This search bar is created in code inside of the `CardViewController` and added separately as a subview to the main view controller - search bar is added to the top of the main view and `cardViewController.view` is added as a draggable bottom sheet.

The user has the possibility to drag this bottom sheet all to the top - which means the search bar would be covered, since it added to the main view separately. - I wan't it to be vise versa.

My approach was to do the following: `searchBar.layer.zPosition`, which kind of worked, but I wasn't able to click the search bar anymore.

**Is there a way to move the search bar to the foreground without preventing interaction?**

```
@IBOutlet weak var searchViewController: UIView!

func viewDidLoad() {
  self.addChild(cardViewController)
  self.view.addSubview(cardViewController.view)

  super.viewDidLoad()    
  searchViewController.addSubview(cardViewController.searchBar)
  cardViewController.searchBar.clipsToBounds = true
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `view.bringSubviewToFront(textField)`? Or is there some reason why you would not be able to do that?

Comment: @MaticOblak I add `cardViewController.view` as a subview, and then `cardViewController.searchBar` to a further UIView inside of the main view controller. I think that's why.

Comment: But do you need it that way? Always try to manipulate order of subviews instead of playing with Z values. In your case looks like that is completely doable. for instance first add a panel for cards `cardPanel`. Then add a panel for search bar `searchBarPanel`. Now add your cards or view with cards to `cardPanel` and your search bar to `searchBarPanel`. Now you can easily manipulate which is in front by simply bringing either `cardPanel` or `searchBarPanel` to front.

Comment: @MaticOblak would you mind to take a look at my edit? That's how I added them. Adding:    `searchViewController.bringSubviewToFront(cardViewController.searchBar)` won't work.

Comment: it is hard to say exactly what are you trying to do here but it might be that you want to bring `searchViewController` to front. Or maybe add the search bar as a subview to `self.view`.

Comment: I added the search bar to searchViewController, which is an UIView, to get the correct position and the correct size for the search bar - I didn't add it to the main view just like the `cardViewController.view`, since I didn't want to struggle with the positioning.